# Java. Выбор поля объекта по строке

Tags: java, парсер, запрос

Есть запрос с параметром. Формат запроса:

> get field1 for field2 = "value1"

Где:

- field1 - одно из полей: ip, user, date, event или status;
- field2 - одно из полей: ip, user, date, event или status;
- value1 - значение поля field2.

Примеры запросов с параметром:

1. get ip for user = "Vasya"
2. get user for event = "DONE_TASK"
3. get event for date = "03.01.2014 03:45:23"

Есть класс

```
class LogObject {
    String ip = "";
    String user = "";
    Date date = null;
    Event event = null;
    Integer eventTask = null;
    Status status = null;

    public LogObject() {
    }
}
```

Есть парсер запроса:

```
public Map<String, String> getFieldsFromQL(String ql) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
        "get (?<field1>\\w+) for (?<field2>\\w+) = \"(?<value1>.*?)\"")
        .matcher(ql);
    if (m.find()) {
        map.put("get", m.group("field1"));
        map.put("for", m.group("field2"));
        map.put("value", m.group("value1"));
    }
    return map;
}
```

Как мне реализовать сбор данных по запросу?

```
public Set<Object> executeQLWithParam(String ql) {
    Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
    ??????????????????????
    return set;   
}
```

Не получается догнать, как обратиться к полю, например, "new LogObject.ip" по String = "ip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу два способа:

рефлексия. почитайте статью [здесь](https://medium.com/@tutorialspointexamples/java-reflection-31161fa37b63)

```
Class c = Class.forName("Class");  
Field field = c.getField("field");
```

или через оператор `switch`

```
switch(name) {
    case "field1":
        object.field1;
        // todo
        break;
}
```

Comment: Интересна реализация с использованием рефлексии. Но все объяснения,которые нахожу, основываются на выводе полей класса. Нужен пример работы с полем именно объекта(ов) класса.

Comment: @in_trance `Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);    
  field.setAccessible(true);
  Object value = field.get(object);`

Comment: Благодарю. Получилось сделась следующим образом:    `for (LogObject logObject : getLogObjects()) {
                Field field1 = logObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(mapParam.get("field1"));
                Field field2 = logObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(mapParam.get("field2"));

                if (field2.get(logObject).toString().contains(mapParam.get("value1")))
                    set.add(field1.get(logObject).toString());
            }`    Однако типы у полей разные и универсального варианта сравнения нет. Поэтому конструкция switch-case предпочтительней